# Add H:M:S value on DateTime field

Tags: java, date, datetime, addition

How to add HOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS value on DateTime field?

On example I want in my field which contains dimetime value to add (sum) with string value which contains value in HH:MM:SECONDS.

ReportDate is `2013-01-01 10:00:00`
Value to add is :`120:34:29`

So result should be: `2013-01-06 10:34:00`

I tried with:

```
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(reportDate);
String toAdd='120:34:29';
c.add(Calendar.HOUR, toAdd);
java.util.Date targetFinish = c.getTime();
SystemOutPrintln(targetFinish.toString());
```

So problematic row is `c.add(Calendar.HOUR, toAdd);`
How to add these value? I want to do it over Gregorian Calendar. And want to have in SysOut that new value;
Thank you

Comment: One word - Joda-time -> http://joda-time.sourceforge.net - This doesn't answer your question, but you'll be thanking yourself later :-)

Comment: You need to parse your text into hours, minutes and seconds and add them individually.  You can't expect it to take a random string of an unknown format.

Comment: @RonDahlgren Or switch the the Java 8 implementation based on JodaTime now.  There is a back port for Java 7 AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(reportDate);

String[] toAdd = "120:34:29".split(":");

int hours = Integer.parseInt(toAdd[0]);
int mins = Integer.parseInt(toAdd[1]);
int secs = Integer.parseInt(toAdd[2]);

c.add(Calendar.SECOND, secs);
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, mins);
c.add(Calendar.HOUR, hours);

java.util.Date targetFinish = c.getTime();

SystemOutPrintln(targetFinish.toString());
```

Comment: I think you must do it reverse? HOURS- MINUTE-SECONDS? OR NOT?

Comment: Do it in any way , result will be same.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse text into hours, minutes and seconds and add them like -

```
String[] time ="120:34:29".split(":");

c.add(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.parseInt(time[0]));
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(time[1]));
c.add(Calendar.SECOND, Integer.parseInt(time[2]));
```

Comment: Hi, thank you but I have two errors first: The method add(int, int) in the type GregorianCalendar is not applicable for the arguments (int, String)

Comment: second: c.add(Calendar.SECOND...) shouldn't be this instead of Second? this is my second error

Comment: Second is still with lower Case?

Comment: change Calendar.Second to Calendar.SECOND