# How to add some time in the system time?

Tags: java, date, datetime

I am trying to get the system date by using the following code . Now i want after adding 123 minutes it should automatically add 2 in hours and three in minutes how is it possible?
  I am using the following code.

```
      try{ 

     SimpleDateFormat  sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
       Date  date = new Date();
       String s = sdf.format(date);
       }

      catch(Exception ex)
       {
       ex.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add H:M:S value on DateTime field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603500/add-hms-value-on-datetime-field)

Comment: You mean, you want to change the system time? Not possible with Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(df.format(date));
    long milSec=date.getTime();
    long addMilSec=123*60*1000;

    long sum=milSec+addMilSec;
    Date d=new Date(sum);

    System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a GregorianCalendar object: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html add you hours/minutes/whatever you need to add and then get back a Date

Answer (score 0):

Create a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object, instead of `Date`, and use `add`.

Example:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 123);
String s = sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
 Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
 now.setTime(YOUR_DATE_OBJECT);//pass your date here

 now.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 50);//add 5o minutes
 now.add(Calendar.SECOND, -50);// subtract 50 seconds
```